# Spontaneous emission as dissipation and fluctuation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-optics, effective-field-theory, non-equilibrium, fluctuation-dissipation

Suppose we have some sort of medium and we want to build an effective theory of *light* inside. Of course we want to calculation the dielectric constant, which in turn is determined by the polarizability, i.e. the response of $\boldsymbol{d} = - e \boldsymbol{r}$ to the electric field.

There however is a problem with the procedure above: it seems we are only considering stimulated emission, while we all know spontaneous emission is always there. If we already have the rate of spontaneous emission, then it can be seen as the inverse of the lifetime of the polarization vector stimulated, which means we have some sort of absorption mechanism in the medium, since the polarization stimulated by an external field can damp on its own.

On the other hand spontaneous emission adds photon to the light field in the medium, which seems not accounted for in the above procedure used to calculate $\chi_e$. It seems the photons from spontaneous emission should be regarded as noise in $\boldsymbol{E}(\boldsymbol{r}, t)$?

So now it seems the effective theory of light within the medium is not a pure-state theory, but a theory with dissipation and fluctuation, and fluctuation-dissipation theorem should follow then. The physical picture seems reasonable; is it correct, and is there any reference concerning this topic? This seems to be a reasonable quantum optics problem, since we may want to know how much a lens makes the state of light more mixed-state, etc.